# TYPO3 login attempts not successful after migration

Tags: typo3

For a project I migrate a TYPO3 based website. After copying files and importing the database successfully, I can't login in the backend. I cleared the cache, TYPO3 also has access to the database (creating new admin account via install tool was successfull, as far as phpMyAdmin says). Also noticeable is the cracked view of the login page (only plain text and fields), maybe there is a coincidence.

So after checking all possibilities, I'm out of ideas. Maybe the hashes aren't correctly created?

Comment: cracked view of the login page suggests that css and js are not loading; from what version to what version you performed the migration?
Maybe there are problems with [BE][loginSecurityLevel] ?

Comment: I just copy-pasted the old files so its 7.6.26 to 7.2.26. all extensions are loading (as install-tool says). loginSecurityLevel is set to `rsa`, as it was on the source-server. I'll check css and js loading again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Style-Problems I had to set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel']`to `0`.

This also fixed the login-issues... I'm glad this helped, although I don't understand why.

Comment: as far as I can remember compressionLevel needs zlib in PHP and rewrite rules for the compressed files

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I'm having problems with the BE Login because of the cookies set by the old website. Try to delete all cookies of the new system and login again.